# How to add a new key value pair to every object inside an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My code:
Scenario 1

```
$newarray = array();

foreach($rows as $k => $v) 
    {
           $newarray[$k] = $v;
           $newarray['newitem'] = 'Add this to existing object';   
    }
echo json_encode($newarray);
```

I tried this as well:
Scenario 2

```
$newarray = array();

foreach($rows as $k => $v) 
    {
           $newarray[$k] = $v;
           $newarray[$k]['newitem'] = 'Add this to existing object';   
    }
echo json_encode($newarray);
```

In scenario 1, key value pair gets added for after 1st object only. It doesn't loop through. 
In scenario 2, i get HTTP ERROR 500

What am I doing wrong here ?

Update:

Existing Output:

```
[{"pid":"123","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"AHHH"},{"pid":"223","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"wwwwAHHH"},{"pid":"223","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"xxxAHHH"}]
```

Required Output:

```
[{"pid":"123","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"AHHH","newkey":"new value1"},{"pid":"223","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"wwwwAHHH","newkey":"new value2"},{"pid":"223","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"xxxAHHH","newkey":"new value3"}]
```

Comment: The first scenario is just wrong. The second should work. Is `$v` an array? Your error may be caused somewhere further down your code. Can you supply an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: Please show what `$rows` contain. Also, show the expected result of `$newarray`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make an temporary array containing what you want and then add it to the newarray, so create a temporary array, add the new data and the existing data, then add that to your newarray

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($rows as $k => $v) 
{
    $t = $v;
    $t['newitem'] = 'Add this to existing object';
    $newarray[$k] = $t;
}
echo json_encode($newarray);
```

EDIT:

Now I know what is in `$rows` is a JSON String this is the way to do what you want. You cannot foreach over a JSON string, you must first convert it to a PHP data structure, then foreach over it adding the new data, then convert it back to a JSON String

```
$rows = '[{"pid":"123","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"AHHH"},{"pid":"223","date":"2016-08-‌​23 08:08:40","post_title":"wwwwAHHH"},{"pid":"223","date":"2016‌​-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"xxxAHHH"}]';

$objArray = json_decode($rows);

$newarray = array();
foreach($objArray as $v) 
{

    $v->newitem = 'Add this to existing object';
    $newarray[] = $v;
}
print_r($newarray);
echo json_encode($newarray);
```

The `$newArray` is now

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pid] => 123
            [date] => 2016-08-23 08:08:40
            [post_title] => AHHH
            [newitem] => Add this to existing object
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pid] => 223
            [date] => 2016-08-‌​23 08:08:40
            [post_title] => wwwwAHHH
            [newitem] => Add this to existing object
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pid] => 223
            [date] => 2016‌​-08-23 08:08:40
            [post_title] => xxxAHHH
            [newitem] => Add this to existing object
        )

)
```

And the new JSON String will be

```
[  {"pid":"123",
    "date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40",
    "post_title":"AHHH",
    "newitem":"Add this to existing object"
   },
   {"pid":"223",
    "date":"2016-08-\u200c\u200b23 08:08:40",
    "post_title":"wwwwAHHH",
    "newitem":"Add this to existing object"
   },
   {"pid":"223",
    "date":"2016\u200c\u200b-08-23 08:08:40",
    "post_title":"xxxAHHH",
    "newitem":"Add this to existing object"
   }
]
```

Comment: Tried this, I get HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: What on earth is in `$rows` then

Comment: $rows = [{"pid":"123","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"AHHH"},{"pid":"223","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"wwwwAHHH"},{"pid":"223","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"xxxAHHH"}]

Comment: See my edit, now we know that you are dealing with a JSON String

Answer (score 1):

In Scenario 1, you are assigning a different value, $v, to the same array key each time so it is just being overridden (and would eventually end up being the value of the last row passed to the foreach):

```
$newarray['newitem'] = 'Add this to existing object';
```

Scenario 2 is on the right lines but needs changing slightly. In Scenario 2 you are adding an array containing $v but then overriding it straight away:

```
$newarray[$k] = $v;
$newarray[$k]['newitem'] = 'Add this to existing object';
```

You need to give the items separate keys so a solution could be to use an 'olditem' key to assign the initial value to:

```
$newarray[$k]['olditem'] = $v;
$newarray[$k]['newitem'] = 'Add this to existing object';
```

There are many solutions you could do depending on how you want the array to be structured but the key principle is to ensure the values have separate keys so they do not override each other.

Comment: Tried this, but the output is like this: [
{"oldItem":{"pid":"123","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"AHHH","newkey":"new value1"},"newItem":"Value 1"},
{"oldItem":{"pid":"123","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"AHHH","newkey":"new value1"},"newItem":"Value 2"},
{"oldItem":{"pid":"123","date":"2016-08-23 08:08:40","post_title":"AHHH","newkey":"new value1"},"newItem":"Value 3"}
 
]

Comment: Can you show the contents of the HTTP 500 error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

You can add new key value in same $row variable.

```
$row = json_decode($row,true);
$row= array_map(function($a) {
          $a += ['newitem' => 'Add this to existing object'];
          return $a;
       }, $row);
    
echo json_encode($row);
```